# Как вызвать метод onNavigationItemSelected с кнопки в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, android-menu

Здравствуйте у меня приложение работает с NavigationDrawer, на первом фрагменте есть несколько кнопок, которые используют то же самые обработчики как и в списке NavigationDrawer, мне нужно как то при нажатие на кнопки, вызвать методы из NavigationDrawer и ставить определенный пункт меню, onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) . Вот так нахожу 
`MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_zapis);` 
И при нажатия на кнопку вызываю метод `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item1)`,
но выдаёт ошибку `Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.view.MenuItem.getItemId()' on a null object reference`.
Я пробовал проверять `if(item1!=null)` но так не выдаёт ошибку но не работает .
подскажите как решить проблему . Спасибо.

Comment: Вот посмотри здесь. Поможет...
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944798/switch-between-fragments-with-onnavigationitemselected-in-new-navigation-drawer)

Comment: @androidx я посмотрел но не нашёл , можете по конкретнее описать ?

Comment: @pavlofff знаете в чем проблема , когда пользователь на главном экране нажимает кнопку , это то же самая кнопка есть списке navigationdrawer ,я хочу хотя бы как то выделить соответствующий пункт списка когда пользователь на главном экране нажимает кнопку.

Comment: То есть ваша реальная проблема - выделить нужный пункт в дровере? Для того, чтобы кто то вам помог не хватает реализации самого дровера и класса, который должен с ним взаимодействовать (откуда нужно выделить пункт)

Comment: @pavlofff navigationdrawer обыкновенный которое использует  пункты из menu.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `NavigationDrawer` построен на `NavigationView`, то выделить один из пунктов этого дровера из фрагмента можно так:

```
NavigationView nv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
nv.getMenu().findItem(id).setChecked(true);
```

где:

- *id* - ID пункта меню, который нужно выделить, например `R.id.nav_zapis`
- *R.id.navigationView* -  ID виджета NavigationView в разметке активити

Comment: Да спасибо , помогло