# Почему не показывает нужный фрагмент при выборе пункта меню nav drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

У меня уже был вопрос по поводу работы с меню -[Как сделать extend нескольких параметров?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875359/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-extend-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2). Вопрос задан неправильно и некорректно. Я изучил вопрос связанный с внедрением фрагментов, мне попалось на глаза [такое видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8GB_b8qyK8). Слепив вместе ответы из моего вопроса и данные полученные из этого видео, я почти достиг поставленной задачи, но не совсем. Если коротко объяснить, то у меня есть в приложении два фрагмента, в каждом из которых размещены списки сообщений (входящие, исходящие). Эти два фрагмента имеют адаптер, который я приводил в своем предыдущем вопросе. И теперь я хочу сделать так, что-бы при нажатии на пункт меню у меня отображался определенный фрагмент. На данный момент у меня только отображается только один фрагмент. Вот что у меня получилось сделать:
В главном классе созданном менюшкой, в методе `onCreate` я добавил такие строки:

```
 mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

дальше там есть функция `onNavigationItemSelected`, и там я описал так выбор пунктов меню:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.received:
                fragment = new Received();
                break;
            case R.id.sent:
                fragment = new Sent();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Received();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

цель довольно проста, при открытии активити с меню, должно по-умолчанию открывать входящие сообщения, например так как в приложении `Gmail`. Я вроде прописал в `default` выбор фрагмента `Received`. Но почему-то при открытии активити с меню, у меня пустой экран, и только после выбора пункта меню `Received` у меня высвечиваются мои входящие сообщения. А вот отправленных сообщений у меня вообще не отображается, вероятнее всего, я не так прописал выбор пунктов меню. Если кто-то заметил у меня ошибку и неправильную логику поведения программы то я буду очень рад если вы мне укажите на нее.

P.S. У меня вот кстати идея возникла - может как-то сделать, что-бы по-умолчанию открывался просто определенный пункт меню, именно тот который относится к фрагменту `Received`?

Comment: вот вроде все одинаковое у двух идентичных фрагментов, но как результат  один открывается нормально, а второй я вообще не могу открыть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот только-что допер как сделать открытие определенного фрагмента при открытии активити с меню. В методе `onCreate` нужно вставить такие строки:

```
Fragment fragment = new Ваш фрагмент();
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(ваш пункт меню).setChecked(true);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

если додумаю как сделать условие, то есть при выборе определенного пункта меню открывать нужный запрос, то обновлю ответ. Вообще стартом моих размышлений был ответ на этот вопрос - [Как вызвать метод onNavigationItemSelected с кнопки в Fragment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637925/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-onnavigationitemselected-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-fragment). Может кому-то поможет мой ответ.